# Bucketable Item is being removed from bucket

Tags: content-editor, buckets

I have an item in Sitecore (10.0.1) that has 'Bucketable' and 'Lock Child Relationship' toggles set to True on their template's standard values:

[image: Settings on the item template's standard values]

Occasionally, we have a situation where certain items have been removed from their buckets. Upon inspection, the settings for Bucketable and Lock Child Relationship have been switched off and we have to go in and click 'reset field' and then sync the buckets. Our client does not know about these settings and would never be in those settings to change them.

[image: Bucketable and Lock Child Relationship toggles have been switched off]

I have checked the different versions of our items and the logs and cannot see why this would be happening. It is quite rare for it to happen but I would like to know why. Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a custom sorting / folder structure rule? If you manually sync the bucket, do any items move unexpectedly?

Comment: Hi @MarcelGruber - yes we have a rule that BucketingRuleContext class that will put the item in a bucket with the same name as whatever is in a ReferenceField for 'Region' and if there is nothing in that field it will be put in a bucket 'Not Specified'. I have checked the history of the item and the region hasn't changed since it became unbucketed.

Answer (score 0):

The key is going to be replicating the issue.

Here are some general recommendations / comments:

- See if the issue is replicable during a deploy; specifically on the content serialization / installation step
- Check the logs for `WARN`/`ERROR`/`AUDIT` entries -- if there is nothing as you have mentioned, then chances are that the issue is with custom code
- It appears that you (and possibly your content authors) are using a Sitecore browser extension, which could be a factor here
- If your bucketable items are based on branch templates, double check that they are configured properly -- this post may help https://catzclw.blog/2023/09/15/solved-sitecore-branch-template-missing-standard-values-on-creation
- Check for any scheduled tasks or custom code which could be a factor
- Run a database cleanup
- Clean up broken links
- Check to see if any of your custom code temporarily disables events
- Check for custom save event handlers, item importation, or data synchronization with external systems
- Note that installing item packages with items contained within a bucket can cause unexpected behavior in some cases
- Confirm whether or not this also happens in other downstream environments